# Finding POIs in Postgresql around point

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, spatial-query, point-of-interest

I'm trying to select POIs from around given location within some distance. I tried so far two approaches I found online, but unfortunately none seems to be working - I'm getting no rows despite the fact I can find records from that area by hand.

My current code is:

(1)

```
SELECT * FROM public.planet_osm_point
WHERE ST_DWITHIN(public.planet_osm_point.way, 
   ST_TRANSFORM(ST_SETSRID(ST_MAKEPOINT(40.6978,-73.9792),4326),3857), 50);
```

(2)

```
SELECT *
FROM public.planet_osm_point
WHERE ST_DWithin(
  ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(40.6978,-73.9792), 3857),
  ST_Transform(public.planet_osm_point.way, 3857),
  500
)
LIMIT 200;
```

Comment: what is the coordinates system for the **public.planet_osm_point.way** ?

Comment: You can get the SRID of osm_point.way using `Find_SRID`, I think the issue is probably because of difference between coordinates system used. http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/Find_SRID.html

Comment: There aren't many points in Antarctica ({lon=40.70, lat=-73.98}).  Did you intend to have a point in Manhattan ({lon=-73.98, lat=40.70})?

Comment: Once you follow @Vince's suggestion, you'll hit the next issue which is that as written your queries will not take advantage of spatial indexes, so you'll have subpar performance.

Comment: In the 2nd query, the coordinates you enter are likely in 4326, not in 3857. As it is written, you are looking around a point a few meters away from 0;0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out there are at least two solutions to my question.

First of all, thanks to Vince's [comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266659/finding-pois-in-postgresql-around-point#comment423561_266659) I started to lok for POIs in Manhattan where I wanted.

Second, as pointed out by Shiko and JGH I have been using different coordinate systems.

The proper query for #1 should be:

```
SELECT * FROM public.planet_osm_point
WHERE ST_DWITHIN(public.planet_osm_point.way, 
   ST_TRANSFORM(ST_SetSRID(ST_MAKEPOINT(-73.9792,40.6978),4326),4326), 0.5);
```

And for #2:

```
SELECT *
FROM public.planet_osm_point
WHERE ST_DWithin(
  ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-73.9792,40.6978), 4326),
  ST_Transform(public.planet_osm_point.way, 4326),
  0.5
)
LIMIT 5000;
```

Please note that I also significantly decreased 3rd argument from 50 to 0.5. Since my type is geometry and not geography this parameter is not distance in meters but 'distance_of_srid' and > 1 starts for SRID 4326 is producing too much results.

However, looking for other clues in different questions/answers I found also idea to add extra index of type geography to be helpful. Indeed, after proceeding as described in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/181206/111883) it works with meters now.